# Why is my data model retaining results of a previous Interpolated SQL query when receiving results of a second query?

Tags: model, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC project in which I want to display two sets of data on the same page. Because of the way the data is stored in my database, I'm using interpolated SQL calls to stored procedures to get my data, as opposed to Linq. Also, while the data itself is different, the data set layout is not, so I'm using the same model to contain the data in both instances.

Here are the two interpolated SQL calls from my context:

```
public virtual async Task<List<DataSet_Model>> GetFirstDataSet() 
    => await Set<DataSet_Model>()
        .FromSqlInterpolated($"EXEC dbo.GetFirstDataSet")
        .ToListAsync();

public virtual async Task<List<DataSet_Model>> GetSecondDataSet() 
    => await Set<DataSetModel_Model>()
        .FromSqlInterpolated($"EXEC dbo.GetSecondDataSet")
        .ToListAsync();
```

In my code, I retrieve the data and bundle it into a container model for delivery to the page like this:

```
public async Task<Container_Model> GetDataSets()
{
     Container_Model model = new Container_Model();

     model.DataSetOne = await _context.GetFirstDataSet();
     model.DataSetTwo = await _context.GetSecondDataSet();

     return model;
}
```

When the results are displayed, I should see something like this:

Data Set A (the contents of DataSetOne)

```
A          Foo          10          20
A          Foo          20          30
```

Data Set B (the contents of DataSetTwo)

```
B          Bar          50          60
B          Bar          60          70
```

Instead, I get this:

Data Set A (the contents of DataSetOne)

```
A          Foo          10          20
A          Foo          20          30
```

Data Set B (the contents of DataSetTwo)

```
A          Foo          10          20
A          Foo          20          30
B          Bar          50          60
B          Bar          60          70
```

The stored procedures themselves work as expected; the stored procedure for `DataSetTwo` isn't returning both A and B rows from the database.

How do I make sure my model is cleared before the second stored procedure query runs?

Comment: Since your code runs correctly in my environment, can you share more relating code? Is there any code before or how you test the stored procedure. 
Give a breakpoint before   **model.DataSetTwo = await _context.GetSecondDataSet();**   to see if the data is correctly bundled.

Comment: @Ronaldoz Sorry, but unless you want to see something in my SQL stored procedures, there's no more code to share.

Comment: It will be great if you can share the stored procedure. So far the problem still cannot be located.